# Answers with code copied from post linked in "Possible duplicate of ..." comment

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

I have seen this in many questions. e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37608354/456135)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37608500/456135) was provided to the above question. The author of this answer just copied the linked code from the auto-generated [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608354/scroll-to-specific-div#comment62700521_37608354) without any extra explanation. How to handle such answers. Should it atleast have a link to the original post? Or do we have any flag for this?